UI elements not rendering when app is launched in profile or release mode
I have been working on this app and it's recently developed this issue where some UI elements don't render in profile/debug mode. I have checked and it is not a routing screen.
class SplashView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashView> createState() => _SplashViewState();
}

class _SplashViewState extends State<SplashView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<SplashViewModel>(
        model: SplashViewModel(),
        onModelReady: (model) async => await model.init(),
        builder: (context, model, _) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: AppColors.primary,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  splashLogo(),
                  80.verticalGap,
                  onboardingContainer(model),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget onboardingContainer(SplashViewModel model) {
    return Container(
      height: 390,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 35),
      width: model.size.width,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            onboardingSlider(model),
            28.verticalGap,
            onboardingText(model),
            15.verticalGap,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45),
              child: AppButton.primary(
                title: "Create an account",
                onTap: () {
                  model.goToSignup(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
            6.verticalGap,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45),
              child: AppButton.ghostPrimary(
                  title: "Login",
                  onTap: () {
                    model.goToLogin(context);
                  }),
            ),
            35.verticalGap,
            onboardingLegalText(model)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  SizedBox onboardingLegalText(SplashViewModel model) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(children: [
            TextSpan(
              text:
                  "By tapping Create an account and using blue, you agree to our ",
              style:
                  AppTextStyles.smallText.copyWith(color: AppColors.textColor),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "Terms ",
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = model.launchTerms,
              style: AppTextStyles.smallText.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: AppColors.primary,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "and ",
              style:
                  AppTextStyles.smallText.copyWith(color: AppColors.textColor),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "Privacy policy",
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = model.launchPrivacy,
              style: AppTextStyles.smallText.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: AppColors.primary),
            )
          ]),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ));
  }

  Container onboardingText(SplashViewModel model) {
    return Container(
      height: 90,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: model.size.width / 8),
      child: Text(
        model.onboardingText[model.index],
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: AppFonts.satoshi,
            color: AppColors.textColor,
            fontSize: 24.5,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget onboardingSlider(SplashViewModel model) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: List.generate(model.onboardingText.length, (index) {
          return AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
            height: 7,
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8) / 3,
            decoration: containerDecoration(index, model),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  BoxDecoration containerDecoration(int index, SplashViewModel model) {
    return BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft:
            index > 0 ? const Radius.circular(0) : const Radius.circular(3),
        bottomLeft:
            index > 0 ? const Radius.circular(0) : const Radius.circular(3),
        topRight: index < model.index
            ? const Radius.circular(0)
            : const Radius.circular(3),
        bottomRight: index < model.index
            ? const Radius.circular(0)
            : const Radius.circular(3),
      ),
      color: model.index >= index ? AppColors.primary : AppColors.grey,
    );
  }

  Widget splashLogo() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      child: Image.asset(
        AppAssets.images.logos.splashLogo.path,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is the UI in question and the onboardingContainer is what is not rendering.
I've tried upgrading Flutter and that didn't help, ran into a debugging loop. Then I reverted and tried updating the UI using widgets like sized box wrapped with decorated box. I also tried reverting to the the version that worked on iOS because the latest version does not but no luck.
Suggestions are welcome and necessary. I ran flutter clean then flutter pub get and after that, profile mode worked fine on the first run and stopped rendering on re-launch/restart.

Does it involve network requests?

@DhafinRayhan it doesn't. These are just static, the only thing controlled by this view is text that changes and navigating to the login and signup pages

what do you mean by "not rendering"? if shows blank container with height == 390? or it does not even occupy any area (size is 0)? or anything else? what about posting the app screenshot?

@pskink It shows that something is occupying the space but it doesn't show what that is. so all of the decorations and elements are not showing but the area seems occupied.

did you try other physical device? maybe your current device is too old for your flutter version?

@pskink I have tried on both android and iOS devices of varying OS versions. It occurred in all of them. Also, I didn't perform any OS updates prior to this occurring.

So, I was able to work around it by separating the UI states into two separate screens. The first just has the splashlogo() while the second has the splashLogo() and onboardingContainer(). the first seems to act as a buffer so the second builds as it should without error.
I'm still open to possible causes for this behaviour and solutions to help avoid it in future.
